# Should there be a separate Stack site for finding scripts, libraries and plug-ins?

Tags: discussion

StackOverflow gets a large number of "do you know of a script that does _____" questions. These usually don't fare very well because the poster isn't asking a question ABOUT code, but is asking FOR code.

These generally come from posters doesn't really know much about coding and are looking for a "quick fix" that does all the work for them.

Sometimes it's someone who has seen a demo of a script, but it doesn't 100% fit their needs and are looking for some "magic version" of the same thing that does exactly what.

The majority of the time the poster has demonstrated that they've done ZERO research on what's available. Rarely do they say they've found a few options and need recommendations.

I think it would be helpful to de-stream these types of questions out of SO and onto their own site.

What do you think? scripting.stackexcahnge.com?

Comment: Put up a http://lists-of-stuff.stackexchange.com proposal on Area 51.

Comment: A lot of people mistake [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) for this very purpose (perhaps due to its name).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The majority of the time the poster has demonstrated that they've done
>   ZERO research on what's available. Rarely do they say they've found a
>   few options and need recommendations.

So we should create a whole stackexchange site for lazy people who can't spend a few hours doing research?

Additionally, answers to these types of questions tend to be *extremely* subjective. People can easily get into religious wars about what the best "widget for XYZ" is. A useful answer for the community is unlikely to emerge out of questions like this.

The right thing to do here is to close the question and tell the asker to come back when they have a specific coding question.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what I do.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that there's a large enough community for it, and that it meets the other requirements set forth at Area51, then [propose it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) and see if it flies.

> **How do I start a new site?**
>
> If your area of expertise doesn't already have a Stack Exchange site,
>   propose it! Stack Exchange sites are free to create and free to use.
>   All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed group of expert
>   users who check in regularly, asking and answering questions.
>
> The creation of Stack Exchange sites is a democratic, community-driven
>   process. That does not mean the majority of Area 51 users have to love
>   your site idea. It simply means you have to recruit a community of
>   users large enough so that questions get good answers quickly. Reach
>   out to other experts to build support for your site; bloggers,
>   enthusiasts, and support groups can all benefit from a world-class,
>   canonical collection of expert answers to the hardest questions.
>
> **Should my idea be part of an existing site, or its own site?**
>
> In general, if a site makes sense as part of a bigger site, it's
>   better to have one big site than a bunch of little niche sites. Site X
>   should be subsumed by site Y if:
>
> - Almost all X questions are on-topic for site Y
> - If Y already exists, it already has a tag for X, and nobody is complaining
> - You're not creating such a big group that you don't have enough experts to answer all possible questions
> - There's a high probability that users of site Y would enjoy seeing the occasional question about X
>
> For more information, read the post Merging Season on the blog.